# Fragments in a ViewPager doesn't refresh and don't show anything

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

After watching and studying every post of this subject, I didn't get a workaround for my bug.

I have a `PagerSlidingTabStrip` which is the selector for my `ViewPager`, and my adapter for the `ViewPager` is :

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{


    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return fragments.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if (position == 0)
            return "ALL";
        else
            return tipos.get(position-1).getNombre();
    }
}
```

I'm hosting the pager on an `Activity`.

The object `fragments` is :

```
HashMap<Integer,PostFragment> fragments = new HashMap<Integer,PostFragment>();
```

and I initilize the HashMap as:

```
public void initHashMap(HashMap<Integer,PostFragment> fragments) {
    if (fragments.size() > 0)
        return;

    PostFragment allFragment = new PostFragment();
    Bundle argsAll = new Bundle();
    argsAll.putInt("tipo", 0);
    argsAll.putSerializable("tipos", (Serializable)tipos);
    allFragment.setArguments(argsAll);
    fragments.put(0, allFragment);

    for (int i = 0; i < tipos.size(); i++) {
        PostFragment fragment = new PostFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("tipo", i+1);
        args.putSerializable("tipos", (Serializable)tipos);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        fragments.put(i+1, fragment);
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM:**
When I swipe, the first time the fragments got loaded. If I swipe a little bit fast, some Fragments start not working anymore when coming back to them.
Sometimes, when I click on the Tab Strip, they don't load either.

I've tried almost all workaround I've tried before.

This is my XML where I host it:

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/parentViews"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rl1" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/pagerBackground"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/searchRL"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/fondoblancoborder" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/borrarEditTextIV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/borrar_edittext" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/busquedaTagET"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/borrarEditTextIV"
                android:ems="10"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch" 
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingRight="5dp" >
            </EditText>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <com.example.help.resources.FlowLayout
            android:id="@+id/tagLL"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/searchRL"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/searchRL"
            android:layout_below="@+id/searchRL"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" >
        </com.example.help.resources.FlowLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@color/pagerBackground" />

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/parentViews" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

**I've tried** as well:

- Dealing with `WeakReference`
- Playing with `.notifyDataChanged()`
- Creating Fragments everytime `getItem()` is called.
- `setRetainInstance(true)`
- Changed from `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to `FragmentPagerAdapter`
- Things that I don't remember anymore because this is the 7th day with this bug.

**Things to know**:

- `getItem(int position)` gets called
- `onCreateView` gets called on every fragment even if it doesn't load

Any clue?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Why did you override [`getItemPosition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#getItemPosition%28java.lang.Object%29) to return `POSITION_NONE`?

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

That would imply that every Fragment is no longer valid for its current position.

> Called when the host view is attempting to determine if an item's
>   position has changed. Returns POSITION_UNCHANGED if the position of
>   the given item has not changed or POSITION_NONE if the item is no
>   longer present in the adapter.

Try removing this method.